# Can someone suggest a design pattern or basic architecture for an application that relies on integrating with 3rd party services

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

Ok so my business constantly strikes deals with various 3rd parties to send data to. Each of these 3rd parties has a different integration technique, for example some will only accept an HTTP GET with query string data.  Others will take an XML form post, while some require us to consume a WCF service.

We post the same data to each 3rd party, with the only major difference being different field name mappings, eg some may use 'ApplicationID' while others use 'AppRef' etc.

I'm trying to come up with a way to structure my application to allow someone to dynamically integrate with a 3rd party without having to write new code.  The mappings can be taken care of by way of mapping tables in the db etc, but my biggest issue is thinking of a way to integrate with various 3rd party services, mainly wcf.

I'd guess this is a pretty common problem in businesses specialising in data providing, so I'm wondering if there's a common approach to it?

Comment: If you're asking for design pattern suggestions, it's because you haven't understood them in depth yet. I suggest you get to know each one, and then the enlightment as to which ones to use will come automatically. Other than that, the question is too broad, and there is no definitive answer for it.

Comment: @Renan I have 3 books on my desk that comprise 2000+ pages of design patterns and messaging/handshake patterns.  I think it's a bit much to expect the asker to have an indepth knowledge of ALL patterns.  He wants some recommendations on what patterns might be applicable to his scenario.  I'm sure if you offered some **constructive** suggestions of useful patterns for his scenario, he would gladly invest time into learning them in depth on his own.  I think it is a bit premature to say he hasn't done due diligence.  He's just looking for pointers in the right direction.

Comment: @AaronLS: +1 for a constructive comment, or a comment promoting constructive reactions.  I wish more on SO thought this way. I just got scolded on another question for saying the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have(and have had) a layer that constructs the common data structure(maybe retrieving some data from your database to create the structure), a data mapping layer that converts it into a structure with property names that coincide to the third party's structure, and a request layer that composes the request.

It sounds like you have some of these figured out already.  If you were doing some sort of "configuration" approach which sounds like what you want, then the request layer would be like an output configuration.  I.e. if you think about many reporting engines, you can choose HTML, CSV, Excel, Interactive, etc. outputs.  If your new 3rd party uses the same conventions as a previous one for XML data, but maybe a slightly different data structure or different data, then you can reuse the same request "category"/RequestType or whatever you want to call it.  I call these RequestTypes personally.  So even though you had to write the code and class for that request type, hopefully if well designed it can be reused.  Each RequestType class should be designed to be reuseable, such as implementing a common base class or interface so that the layer before it that has to call it can easily do so generically.

A factory pattern that allows you to call something like `GetRequestType( database.SomeThirdParty.RequestTypeEnumValue )` which takes an enum or string indicating a RequestType and returns a class.  Since that class should implement some common interface/base class, it can proceed to pass in the data structure and call things like SendRequest() without having to know which request type class it's working with.

The nice thing about this is when you run into situations where the 3rd party's implementation is completely incompetent, and you have to write special code just for them, then you can create a new RequestType class just for them.  It would be a challenging task to create a system that allows 3rd party integration completely through configuration, and could handle all possible scenarios.  When I've seen systems so complicated that they allow completely codeless implementations like this, you end up with some pretty convoluted things.  Again on the report engine analogy, I have seen some pretty convoluted things in reports that would have been alot more straightforward to do in code.  Yeh the report engine was "sophisticated" enough to let someone do it, but at what cost?

Comment: Thanks, yeh it makes sense to have the RequestType and the configuration solution is what I'm ultimately aiming for. I've taken over this application from previous developers and am looking to rewrite most of it seeing as there's a hell of a lot of duplication that could really be solved by configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid trying to generalize something as complex as data mapping and transport. Ultimately, your code will be harder to understand than if you simply had this:

```
public interface IDataExportTarget
{
    async Task ExportDataAsync(YourDataType data);
}
```

Not only could the data transport mechanism differ (WCF, RESTful interfaces, etc), but your data format may also differ (CSV, XML, JSON, etc) as well as how you package the data while transporting it. Certainly, you could have common abstract base classes if you have common export concerns:

```
public abstract class XmlDataExportTarget : IDataExportTarget
{
    public async Task ExportData(YourDataType data)
    {
        var xml = MapDataToXml(data);
        await SendXmlDataAsync(xml);
    }

    protected abstract XDocument MapDataToXml(YourDataType data);
    protected abstract async Task SendXmlDataAsync(XDocument data);
}
```

...but you should only do this once you find your code is causing you to repeat yourself.

Comment: It's an existing code base that I need to build on and there's already loads of duplication in place. I'm planning on leaving the existing third party integrations as is, however extract much of the duplication for newer integrations which will hopefully allow me to eventually update the legacy 3rd parties.